# How can I fix Android Studio's broken GUI?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-studio

I'm working with Android Studio on Windows 10 and today it started up like this:

[image]

Any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it's a known issue on Windows. I've seen it on many Windows machines. So I guess you have to wait for an update or use Linux for a better experience...

Comment: It's a shame that we are almost at 2019 and we can still experience this...

Answer (score 1):

Reset Android Studio to default settings and you should be fine.

Close Android Studio and Delete the folder:

```
C:\Users\<username>\.AndroidStudio1.5 (or which ever version you are on right now)
```

Start Android studio and all settings would have reverted back to default.